# Problem with downloading Excel file stored in server with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am storing excel files directly in the server.
I am uploading it via API and it works fine.

Now I want separate API for downloading the selected file. The download somehow doesn't work in the Postman yet and I don't know what I am doing wrong..

Source code

Route:

```
router.get(
  "/downloadExcel/:id",
  postController.downloadExcel
);
```

Controller:

```
exports.downloadExcel = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {    
    const post= await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    let fileName: string = post.newExcelPath.replace(
      "/utilities/uploaded-excels/",
      ""
    );

    res.setHeader(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    );
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

    let dirname: string = __dirname.replace("/controllers", "");

    const fileStream = fs
      .createWriteStream(dirname + post.newExcelPath)
      .on("error", (error: any) => console.log(error))
      .on("finish", () => {
        res.download(dirname + "/utilities/uploaded-excels/" + fileName);    
        res.status(200).json(post);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: err });
  }
};
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: How do you expect the file be displayed in Postman? The response looks gibberish b/c Excel is not a textual file format. Try downloading the file from your API and opening it from your computer, it should be fine.

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem.. In the browser it worked fine haha.. what a stupid mistake I did